# Why is the image under integration of a uniformly bounded subset of $C[a,b]$ necessarily compact?

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

I am studying for qualifying exams and ran into this problem in Carothers:

Define $T: C[a,b] \rightarrow C[a,b]$ by $(Tf)(x) = \int_a^x f$. Show that $T$ maps bounded sets into equicontinuous (and hence compact) sets.

I have proven that $T(F)$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous if $F$ is bounded. However, to use Arzela-Ascoli to show that $T(F)$ is compact I also need that $T(F)$ is closed. I can't see why $T(F)$ is necessarily closed simply given that $F$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: $F$ is bounded into $\overline{T(F)}$ which is compact. If $F$ is bounded, I don't think it is true that $T(F)$ is closed, the set $\{ cx : c \in (0,1) \}$ is I think a counterexample.

Comment: I think you're right. Add one to the list of Carothers errata (there is actually a lot I have found)

Comment: Certainly the title is wrong. But then you write "$T$ maps bounded sets into equicontinuous (and hence compact) sets". We have a problem with the English language here. Are we saying that "equicontinuous = compact"? Or are we saying "$T$ maps bounded sets into compact sets"? The latter statement is correct.

Comment: I literally copied the problem statement from Carothers. I think they meant that since T(F) is equicontinuous and bounded it is compact, which is incorrect if you look at the counter example provided by N.S.

Comment: Perhaps they mean to show that $T$ is a compact operator?

Comment: I don't think so as compact operators have not been defined at this point in Carothers (and I don't think are ever defined in the book)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to supply N.S.'s comment as an answer here and accept it, because I think that it is the correct response to the question.

Carothers' claim in parentheses, that T sends bounded sets to compact sets, is incorrect.

Take the subset of $C[0,1]$, $F = \{c | c \in (0,1)\}$. $F$ is clearly uniformly bounded. And $T(F) = \{cx | c \in (0,1)\}$. Consider the sequence $f_n$ in $T(F)$ defined by $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n+1}x$. $f_n$ has no convergent subsequence. Therefore $T(F)$ is not compact.